# Excel If text then number function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create an Excel function which would return results as follows:
If `B2` is `Frontiera`, then display the value from `J5` in `B1`, if `B2` is `Lleida`, then display the value from `J6` in `B1`, if `B2` is `Girona`, then display the value from `J7` in `B1`... and so on. I looked into it but it gets me really confused.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative intended to be more extensible:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"Frontiera","Lleida","Girona"},0),J6,J7,J8)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a series of nested `IF` functions calls.  Into cell `B1` enter:

```
=IF(B2="Frontiera", J5, IF(B2="Lleida", J6, IF(B2="Girona", J7, "Other")))
```

I have assumed that you want to display `Other` in the case where there is no match.  You may continue with the above approach to handle more cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a cross-reference table and intend to hard code the lookup values instead, put this standard formula in B1.

```
=iferror(index(j5:j9, match(b2, {"frontiera", "lleida", "girona", "abc", "def"}, 0)), "other")
```

Adjust the j5:j9 and string literal array for more or less values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either vlookup or index with match as shown:

[image]

Cell B1 has the vlookup and cell b4 has the index with match...